# How to manage multi user in the same browser application without having to logout/login all the time with azure ad/application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, bearer-token

With Azure AD application I need to be able to login multi users in the same browser on the same computer and switch between them without having to login/logout all the time.

Now, every time I try to login another use, I need to logout the current!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `prompt=select_account` on the login requests from your app. This will force account selection each time, instead of just signing in with active account.

You can see documentation for this at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Then it's a matter of handling those multiple sessions on your app's side.

Comment: With this parameter, I can now select another remembered account from the list or enter another one, but I still need to logout the previous session in the next step.